# order of (), +, -, *, / and other relational operators in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am practicing the relational operators. The question is "check if -6 * 14 is not equal to 17 - 101. I tried it in two way.

```
-6*14 != 17-101
# [1] FALSE

(-6*14) != (17-101)    
# [1] TRUE
```

Can anyone explain for me why is this?

Comment: Type `?"Syntax"` into your console.

Comment: This `(-6*14) != (17-101)` still gives FALSE. Recheck it

Answer (score 2):

Here's the order of operations from the `?Syntax` help page

```
:: :::       access variables in a namespace
$ @          component / slot extraction
[ [[         indexing
^            exponentiation (right to left)
- +          unary minus and plus
:            sequence operator
%any%        special operators (including %% and %/%)
* /          multiply, divide
+ -          (binary) add, subtract
< > <= >= == !=     ordering and comparison
!            negation
& &&         and
| ||         or
~            as in formulae
-> ->>       rightwards assignment
<- <<-       assignment (right to left)
=            assignment (right to left)
?            help (unary and binary)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for all answers!